# Can't collect Critic badge

Tags: support, badges

Is it normal that it can take some time to receive a badge? I have down-voted a question and normally you collect the [Critic badge](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/badges/7/critic). So far the badge hasn't been awarded.

Comment: Badges are awarded when system jobs run so give it a bit of time. Also, voting is supposed to be anonymous, you've just shown everyone that you downvoted several posts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Badges are not awarded immediately - many of them are only calculated once daily, so you'll need to give it more than 11 minutes to kick in.

Update: [Critic has now been awarded](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/66634/hein?tab=badges).

Comment: It is not on meta bit it is over here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/66634/hein?tab=votes

Comment: @Hein The vote tab on your profile is only available to you because _voting is anonymous_.

Comment: @Hein sorry, your question was originally worded "I had a question down-voted" which is different than "I down-voted a question."

Comment: @bluefeet oke I didn't know that.